# get value from the url using json

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

I am try to get asciiName From this url:-

```
http://services.gisgraphy.com/geoloc/search?lat=21.283300399780273&lng=72.9832992553711&radius=10000<br>
```

using ajax jsonp. 
this is full code:-

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<Script>

var asciilast;
var asciiname="";
var lat="21.283300399780273";
var lng="72.9832992553711";
var radius="10000";

function getascii(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://services.gisgraphy.com/geoloc/search?lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng+"&radius="+radius+"&format=json",
    async: false,
    dataType:'jsonp',
    success: function(data1) {
      for(i=0;i<data1.result.length;i++) {
        asciiname = asciiname+data1.result[i].asciiName+",";
        console.log(asciiname);
        asciilast = asciiname.replace(/\,$/, '');
      }
      alert(asciilast);
    }
  });   
}
</Script>
<body onload="getascii()">
</body>
```

with help of this code I am getting perfect output.
but some times it generates problems like some results have no asciiName then it returns undefined.

if result has no asciiName then I don't want undefined

Comment: Also change  `function getascii(){` to `window.onload=function() {` or better: `$(function() { ... });` and remove the onload from the body tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    asciiname = '';
    asciilast = '';

    if(data1.result[i].asciiName){
        asciiname = asciiname+data1.result[i].asciiName+",";
        console.log(asciiname);
        asciilast = asciiname.replace(/\,$/, '');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

than check for undefined

```
var value = data1.result[i].asciiName || "";
```

or

```
var value = data1.result[i].asciiName;
if (value) {
   //do work here
}
```

Comment: This is not really a check for ´undefined´, say for example the name that is returned is "0" or "null", just 2 examples. If you are going to check for ´undefined´ then it is better to be explicit: either ´typeof value === "undefined"´ or if you jslint your code then I would suggest: ´var undef; value === undef´. It would be better to say that is a "falsey check" which includes ´undefined´

Comment: @Xotic750 The value is a string so it will not be a fasley value! The key will either not be there or have a string value. Look at the JSON/XML response.

Comment: @Xotic750 With this service, the tag will be there if there is a name for the location. If it does not have it, there will be no name. There will NOT be a null, empty string, 0, false, etc. The check is 100% valid in this situation.

Comment: I agree with you in this case, the string is not falsey but the check is, though I feel that it is safer to differentiate for the reader, there will then be less confusion/chance of mistake, when the same pattern "x = something || somethingelse" arises in other code where the value could be something other than a string. If it had been clear then you would not have needed your above explanation as to why this is so in this case. This is just my opinion, and there is nothing syntactically wrong etc with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
asciiname = asciiname + data1.result[i].asciiName+",";// this line
```

Assign a default value to it:

```
asciiname += data1.result[i].asciiName ? data1.result[i].asciiName : "default value";
```

Or if you want to avoid `if`s of any kind:

```
asciiname += data1.result[i].asciiName || "default value";
```

Replace `"default value"` with whatever you want there. I am using a ternary if condition:

```
(condition) ? a : b; // equivalent to if(condition) {a} else {b};
```

Comment: In this case, that would be better written as: ´asciiname += data1.result[i].asciiName || "default value";´

Answer (score 1):

have a check like-

```
jQuery.type(data1) === "undefined" or `jQuery.type(data1.result[i])=== "undefined"`
```

in the `success` method and handle the logic accordingly.